# Son is bypassing parental controls

Tags: macos, parental-controls

I have set weekday time limits & bedtime under parental controls, but my son and his friends have figured out how to bypass them. When he gets a notification that he has x time remaining, I have seen him switch rapidly to mission control and then the notification goes away and never logs him off.  I am running Mavericks.  Does anyone know if they fixed this bug in Yosemite?  I logged an issue with Apple and they never responded.

Comment: regardless what you do, you are stuck with a computer genius who will always find a way to trick the system :) -- if you have Apple Airport Extreme you can set additional parietal controls there. http://www.apple.com/lae/airportextreme/features/security.html

Comment: props to your son!

Comment: Yosemite is free? Why not upgrade and test it out?

Comment: I run bootcamp and as far as I can tell, Apple hasn't fixed the issues they are having with upgrades.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602253

Comment: I did upgrade to Yosemite and he is still able to thwart parental controls.  He has now figured out how to bypass Windows 8 parental controls as well.

Comment: You should be proud of him, he may have a promising career in CS ahead of him! In the meantime, if he's doing well in school, don't worry so much about his weekday computer usage. Enforce bedtime physically in person, if he's playing online games after bedtime, then just turn off the router. Most importantly, on weekends offer an alternative to computers; go hiking, camping, fishing, _anything_ but being inside on computers - invite and bring his friends - you will **not** get a second chance at this.

Comment: This is what I eventually ended up doing.  Plugging the router into a power strip with scheduling to automatically switch off at a certain time at night.  Thanks.